# Select en una función en Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Es simple he creado una función sencilla que me trae la cantidad de registros de una tabla, solo eso

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_getGeneralReport()
Returns integer as $func$
BEGIN
select
    count(*)
    -- name as Nombre_Grabacion,
    -- starttime,
    -- endtime,
    -- endtime - starttime as duration,
    -- participants,
    -- record_id
from
    public.recordings;
END
```

Y cuando creo la función, me devuelve ha sido creado correctamente

```
Query returned successfully in 335 msec.
```

Pero a la hora de llamarlo falla, y me devuelve este error

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function sp_getgeneralreport() line 4 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601
```

La forma como lo llamo es

```
select sp_getGeneralReport();
```

He buscado y no encuentro el error, la documentación no me dice nada relevante y no tengo la menor idea en que estoy fallando (normalmente trabajo sobre mysql, estoy aprendiendo).

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Escribe como lo llamas acuérdate que los procedimientos no devuelven nada para devolver se utilizan funciones revisa bien

Comment: Y me parece que en este caso lo que te hace falta es una función y no un procedimiento

Comment: @Japv he corregido el sp para que ahora sea una función, pero aún así sigue el mismo error, retornando un integer para ver que funcione al menos, retorna error.

Comment: Error amigo, lo que debes retornar es el select investiga sobre cursores te va a servir

Comment: Ya he trabajado sobre cursores (Mysql, no croe que cambie mucho), lo que necesito es que me devuelva el registro completo que le estoy pidiendo, estoy enlistando toda la tablla con las columnas que tengo, lo cual ya esta, y me sirve. gracias por tu ayuda, al darme cuenta que los no retornar datos como en mysql me dejo terminar,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estos son los cambios que deberías implementar:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_getGeneralReport()
Returns integer as $TotalRegistros$
declare
    TotalRegistros integer
BEGIN
  select count(*) into TotalRegistros
         from
         public.recordings;
  return TotalRegistros;
END
```

Detalle:

- Declaramos una variable `TotalRegistros` para recibir el resultado del `count`
- Asignamos la salida del `count` mediante `select count(*) into TotalRegistros`
- Por último retornamos el valor obtenido con `return TotalRegistros;`